# multiple forms on MainWindow.ui using Qt creator

Tags: qt

how do I put the time, date and company logo on the top of all my Qt forms?
I don't want to redo this same code in all my classes.
I thought I could create 1 class with a stacked widget for the date, time and logo and then call (add) this to all other classes.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In QML, you would generally put the common code in a base class and subclass it to create children that might have values to certain fields that are different - but the same common fields. I use this technique to generate different modes in the same app that might need slightly different toolbars but the same canvas.

You might want to write the ui code in c++ for widgets, and then go from there.

Another approach might be to set the common values inside a model, and use those common values across the board.

Comment: I do have my "common" code in separate class. I 'm not sure have to call that from the mainWindows.ui class to be displayed.
And what container do I use to display these in the mainWindows.ui class and other classes (forms). 
Is there an example I can reference?

Comment: Here is an example that subclasses in the way i suggested: https://www.informatik.fb2.frankfurt-university.de/~doeben/I-PROGR3/I-PROGR3-MAT/html/designer-manual-6.html  Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: I'm still unclear with the suggestion link provided.
I have 5 forms in my project; "A.ui", "B.ui", "C.ui", "D.ui" and "E.ui".
I want all 5 of these forms to display the date/time, logo, etc at the top of the form.
can I create a "logo.ui" form and call this form from each of the other forms to be displayed so I don't have to duplicate the same code in all 5 forms?
I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: As you can see in the example, it takes a reverse approach to what you just said, but its consistent as an answer to your question. Your common view is your UI file, your extensions are in C++ that subclass the ui. I don't think it can get any clearer than the section that literally outlines how to do this titled "Creating Dynamic Dialogs from .ui Files" . How does my solution NOT answer the original question?  Alternatively, Just create another component that goes into your UI? https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html